# How to get docker to work correctly in guest Windows machine on VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtualization, hyper-v, docker-for-windows

On my host system ( Arch Linux ) I have created two guest Windows machines ( Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 ) in VirtualBox.

VT-x/AMD-V is enabled and also Nested Paging.

I have installed Docker Desktop on Win10 / installed the docker package from PowerShell on Win Serv 2019.

I have enabled Hyper-v and Container optional features.

On both systems I get the following error when trying to run a container:
`Error response from daemon: hcsshim: :CreateComputeSystem e18e6cde13568ea0323aaaa03afc00a45659641f6284fbb7b92a: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.`

Comment: VirtualBox does not pass through the needed CPU features to nest Hyper-V.

Comment: what would you suggest for this? QEmu?

Comment: QEMU/KVM allow more CPU features to pass through (https://www.mess.org/2020/06/22/Hyper-V-in-KVM/).  Why not just run Docker natively on Linux?

Comment: I need to test Dynamics 365 and Microsoft SQL Server containers in their native env